# Combining the rows of a dataframe where each row is a df itself

Tags: r, list, dataframe, join, merge

I have an object with each row being a dataframe or list itself like this:

```
[[1]]
1: a b c d
   1 1 2 4

[[2]]
1: a b c d
   4 3 6 2

[[3]]
1: a b c d 
   1 2 2 1
```

How can I transform this to a dataframe like below?

```
a b c d 
1 1 2 4
4 3 6 2
1 2 2 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `rbindlist`

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(lst1)
```

---

Or with `rbind` and `do.call` in `base R`

```
do.call(rbind, lst1)
```